# How to start Lumina by default? [OpenBSD]

Tags: x11, desktop-environment, openbsd, startx, lumina

**Question**: How do I configure OpenBSD to start [Lumina](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumina_(desktop_environment)) by default instead of OpenBSD's default desktop environment?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `exec start-lumina-desktop` to `.xsession` in your home dir.